Getting TypeError: <lambda>() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given while importing libraries from PEFT
I am trying to Fine-Tune Code-llama, and I am referring to a blog for it.
I am getting issues in Import,
!pip install git+https://github.com/huggingface/transformers.git@main bitsandbytes  # we need latest transformers for this
!pip install git+https://github.com/huggingface/peft.git@4c611f4
!pip install datasets==2.10.1
import locale # colab workaround
locale.getpreferredencoding = lambda: "UTF-8" # colab workaround
!pip install wandb
!pip install scipy
from datetime import datetime
import os
import sys

import torch
from peft import (
    LoraConfig,
    get_peft_model,
    get_peft_model_state_dict,
    prepare_model_for_int8_training,
    set_peft_model_state_dict,
)
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForCausalLM, TrainingArguments, Trainer, DataCollatorForSeq2Seq

I get a long error with this, I can't put entire error but will add the important parts
> > --------------------------------------------------------------------------- TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
> > last) Cell In[2], line 5
> >       2 import os
> >       3 import sys
> > ----> 5 from peft import (
> >       6     LoraConfig,
> >       7     get_peft_model,
> >       8     get_peft_model_state_dict,
> >       9     prepare_model_for_int8_training,
> >      10     set_peft_model_state_dict,
> >      11 )
> >      12 from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForCausalLM, TrainingArguments, Trainer,
> DataCollatorForSeq2Seq
> > File /usr/lib/python3.8/_pyio.py:249, in open(file, mode, buffering, encoding, errors, newline, closefd, opener)
>     247 if binary:
>     248     return result
> --> 249 text = TextIOWrapper(buffer, encoding, errors, newline, line_buffering)
>     250 result = text
>     251 text.mode = mode
> 
> File /usr/lib/python3.8/_pyio.py:2014, in TextIOWrapper.__init__(self,
> buffer, encoding, errors, newline, line_buffering, write_through)   
> 2012             encoding = "ascii"    2013         else:
> -> 2014             encoding = locale.getpreferredencoding(False)    2016 if not isinstance(encoding, str):    2017     raise
> ValueError("invalid encoding: %r" % encoding)
> 
> TypeError: <lambda>() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

My python version is 3.8.10 and my machine is Lenovo L480 (16gb ram i5)
My GPU configs are
*-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: UHD Graphics 620
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 07
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:130 memory:f0000000-f0ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:e000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff

When I comment the
import locale # colab workaround
locale.getpreferredencoding = lambda: "UTF-8" # colab workaround

I get error related to GPU (more like you don't have GPU).
PS- I am executing this code on Jupyter lab for now.
Thank you in advance, I really need to move up since I am stuck here for days now.
Can someone acknowledge, if they're able to get pass through the installations successfully. I would highly appreciate if you guide me with that.

I tried running this on google colab - import locale  # colab workaround
locale.getpreferredencoding = lambda do_setlocale=True: "UTF-8"
import torch
from peft import (LoraConfig,get_peft_model,get_peft_model_state_dict,prepare_model_for_int8_training,set_peft_model_state_dict,)
got - /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/init.py in 
560     raise  # If file is not None the cause is unknown, so just re-raise.
--> 562 for name in dir(C):
563     if name[0] != '' and not name.endswith('Base'):
NameError: name '_C' is not defined
